# recursive descend parser - avoiding left recursion

Tags: parsing, recursive-descent, left-recursion

I have the following productions

```
A -> Aa
A -> b
```

so it is clear that there is left recursion like

```
parseA() {
   parseA();//recursion
   parsea();
}
```

It is said that the left recursion can be avoided using the following rule

```
A -> bA'
A' -> aA'|null
```

How is left recursion avoided here?.There is still recursion in function A'.
Can anybody explain me this.I am a beginner in this subject?

Comment: Write out the function to see what's happening. The recursion is now tail recursion instead of left recursion.

Comment: what is actually this 'left' recursion

Comment: It is not polite to enter all active chatrooms and greet people with nothing but a link to your seconds-old question.

Comment: You tell me what left recursion is. You're the one who brought it up. You can read your textbook or ask your teacher.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Oh he got the lounge too did he? :)

Comment: @Leigh Yep, he just came in, dumped the question, then left. Not really great etiquette if you ask me.

Comment: Dont have teacher or book...just studied from web!

Comment: sorry for the disturbance..I just wanted somebody notice my post..so that i may get it answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is left recursion avoided here?.There is still recursion in function A'.

Read this again. Left recursion is avoided. Non-left recursion is not.

Comment: so there is still recursion in the function A'?

Comment: also what is actually this 'left' recursion ?

Comment: Recursion of the leftmost element. So rules like `A = A something` are left recursive. Non-left-recursion is fine for all LL parsers.